# Mostrar todo o conteúdo do span independente do tamanho

Tags: html, css

Estou com um probleminha na hora de mostrar um texto em minha tela:

Tenho uma tag span com id="obsEmenda" que recebe um varchar do servidor:

```
<span class="progress-description">OBSERVA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O: <strong><span id="obsEmenda"></span></strong></span>
```

O texto desse span está ultrapassando o tamanho do container e não mostra o restante.
Queria achar um modo de quebrar esse texto para que apareça todo na tela. Seria o caso de utilizar um textarea?
Imagem de como está:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam que ele coloca 3 pontos no final devido a algumas propriedades da classe 'progress-description'.

```
.progress-description {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: inclua a parte relevante do CSS, assim como o container que está escondendo o overflow

Comment: O container é esse primeiro span

Comment: Entendi, então o css da #progress-description e da #obsEmenda

Comment: Vou colocar o css dessa classe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se vc quer que a linha quebre vc precisa remover algumas coisas do seu CSS como o `white-space: nowrap;` e    `overflow: hidden;`

Depois vc adiciona a propriedade `word-break: break-all;` para quebrar a palavra, mesmo se ele for uma palavra grande como esses "mmmmmmm" que coloquei no exemplo abaixo

Veja como fica no exemplo:

```css
.progress-description {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<span class="progress-description">OBSERVA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O: 
    <strong><span id="obsEmenda">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, rerum. mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
    </span></strong>
</span>
```

Comment: show mano, obrigado ;)

Comment: @MayconF.Castro tmj jovem! Não deixe de dar uma olhadinha nos links citados no comentários, lá tem outras variações para o uso dessa propriedade que podem te ajudar no futuro!